# How to assign XSLT variables with XML attributes

Tags: xslt

Here is my XML file:

```
<Veranstaltungen xmlns="urn:schemas-etourist:Veranstaltung">
    <Veranstaltung attribute1="xyz" attribute2="xyz">
        <OBJECT>
            <string xmlns="urn:eTourist:i18n" xml:lang="de-DE">GERMAN TEXT</string>
            <string xmlns="urn:eTourist:i18n" xml:lang="en-GB">ENGLISH TEXT</string>
            <string xmlns="urn:eTourist:i18n" xml:lang="cs-CZ">CZECH TEXT</string>
        </OBJECT>
...
```

And here my XSLT variables:

```
...
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:td="urn:schemas-etourist:Veranstaltung"
xmlns:td2="urn:schemas-etourist:SchemaExtension"
xmlns:td3="urn:eTourist:i18n"
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
extension-element-prefixes="php">
...
<xsl:variable name="german">
<xsl:value-of select="td:OBJECT/td3:string[@xml:lang='de-DE']"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="english">
<xsl:value-of select="td:OBJECT/td3:string[@xml:lang='en-GB']"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>
...
```

Variable 'german' is filled correctly, HOWEVER variable 'english' is filled with the GERMAN TEXT value. How do we fill variable 'english' with the ENGLISH TEXT value?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: your `$english` variable should have the `ENGLISH TEXT` value, based upon what you posted. Although, your source XML doesn't appear to be bound to different namespaces for the `<OBJECT>` and `<string>` elements. Are the `td` and `td3` namespace prefixes bound to the same namespace, or different? You might need to post more complete examples to help troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have posted except that, as Mads says, you have two different namespaces in your XSLT whereas the XML has just one. You need to publish a more complete account of what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Mads and Borodin for the quick response. Have edited the question with the namespaces in use. Hope this helps to find the problem.

Comment: From what you've provided us, it looks fine. What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @JLRishe: the variable "english" is filled with "GERMAN TEXT" instead of "ENGLISH TEXT"

Comment: Seems to work fine when I try it. Could you provide us a more complete view of your XSLT, particularly the template where these variables are located, and where they are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`lang()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-lang), which is designed to match languages like this, taking account of scope (remember an `xml:lang` attribute applies to all descendant elements as well as to the element on which the attribute is specified):

```
<xsl:variable name="german">
<xsl:value-of select="td:OBJECT/td3:string[lang('de')]"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="english">
<xsl:value-of select="td:OBJECT/td3:string[lang('en')]"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>
```